# VIM substitute occurrences of pattern after a particular word in a line

Tags: vim, regular-expression, vi

I have such lines in my text.

> text before pattern = garbage** text after pattern is pattern

If in VIM I do `%s/pattern/saturn/` it replaces all occurrences of `pattern`. But I only want to replace those occurrences that come after `=`. It should ignore everything in the line that occurs before `=`. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the special atom `\@<=` to assert a match *before* (`=.*` to make it *anywhere* before in that line):

```
:%s/\(=.*\)\@<=pattern/saturn/g
```

Comment: could you explain how this works?

Comment: Read `:help /\@<=` (I can't explain it better), but don't feel bad when you don't get it first. It's called _positive lookbehind_, and is quite advanced.

Comment: +1 Really elegant. The interesting thing is, variable width lookbehind isn't supported in Perl! I never thought the Perl regex engine would ever be lacking something other engines have.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have only one occurrence of `pattern` before `=`, you can do this in two steps:

```
:%s/pattern/saturn/g
:%s/saturn\(.\{-}=\)/pattern\1/
```

The `\{-}` instructs `.` to match lazily (aka non-greedily).

**Explanation**

This first step replaces all the occurrences of `pattern` by `saturn` the next step then looks for the word `saturn` before `=` and replaces it with `pattern`.

**Caution**

This assumes a single occurrence of `=` on each line.

**A better way (only assumes a single `=` per line)**

You can do it with a recursive macro:

```
qaqqa:%s/\(=.\{-}\)pattern/\1saturn/@aq@a
```

This substitutes a single occurrence of `pattern` after `=` with `saturn`. When stored as a macro and called recursively it will keep working on the file until there's nothing left to substitute. It's hackish but it works.

**See also**

- [How can I make my match non-greedy in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305853/how-can-i-make-my-match-non-greedy-in-vim)
- [Record a recursive macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Record_a_recursive_macro)

Comment: Will this replace all occurrences of pattern after =? How? I don't know how many there will be beforehand.

Comment: @user13107 My original answer replaced only a single instance of `pattern` after `=`. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks mate, that was clever, unfortunately there are an unknown number of them before `=` :( argh

Comment: @user13107 I have a hack to work around this. Will post when I have time.

Comment: this also assumes that the string `saturn` isn't in the text.  probably true, but i'd be inclined to use something a lot more obscure/unique as the temporary substitute string - `myhamsterlivesonsaturn`, perhaps :)

Comment: @user13107 Please see updated answer.

Comment: Hi Joseph, i'm inclined to accept the other answer which seems more clean. But thanks for teaching about macro!

Comment: @user13107 Hey, it's your question.